# Call native objective methods from JavaScript using JavaScript core framework

Tags: javascript, ios, javascriptcore

Suppose I have three classes.

1. A view controller with a button present on it.
2. JavaScript file with some JavaScript methods.
3. Model objective class with some methods of calling web-service.

When I press button on view controller, it calls `.js` (JavaScript file) and in return `.js` file calls methods from model class.

I just want to know if it is possible using JavaScript core framework without using web view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Objective-C interface in the JavascriptCore framework introduced with iOS 7 / OS X 10.9 permits calling Objective-C methods from Javascript and calling Javascript functions from Objective-C. Both of these scenarios can occur without involving a webview.  For a great intro to these features, check out the 2013 WWDC introduction "Integrating JavaScript into Native Apps" session on Apple's developer network: https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/?id=615

Below is a simple example.  You can also create more sophisticated examples that directly expose existing methods via the JSExport protocol (see the pdf/video above).

myJavascript.js:

```
function myJavascriptFn(arg) {
    myObjC_callback(arg); // Call Objective C code
}
```

myView.m:

```
#import <JavaScriptCore/JavaScriptCore.h>

....

javascriptContext  = [[JSContext alloc] init]; // Create a standalone javascript VM and context.

// Load the javascript file into the VM
NSURL *scriptURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"path/to/myJavascript.js"];
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *script = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:scriptURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
[javascriptContext evaluateScript:script];

// Set up calling an Objective-C callback for Javascript to use
javascriptContext[@"myObjC_callback"] = ^(NSString *arg) {
    NSLog(@"Calling someObjectiveCMethod from javascript.  Passed arg is:%@", arg);
    [self someObjectiveCMethod:arg];
}

// Call javascript from Objective C
JSValue *myJavascript_callback = javascriptContext[@"myJavascriptFn"];
[myJavascript_callback callWithArguments:@[@"test arg"]];
```

The JavascriptCore framework also provides built-in conversion between common Objective-C types and Javascript types.  See my answer to [How is an ObjC JS bridge translated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23047512/how-is-an-objc-js-bridge-translated/23050131#23050131) for more details.

Comment: Mike, suppose if i have two or three functions in one myJavascript.js file , then how can i select individual functions. Because if we provide the path for a .js file, then complete file is read in one go. Any suggestions if you can provide on this.

Comment: You can include as many javascript functions as you want in your myJavascript.js file.  Once it has been loaded and evaluated by `[javascriptContext evaluateScript:script]` then individual functions are accessed from Objective-C by `JSValue *myFn1 = javascriptContext[@"myFn1"]; [myFn1 callWithArguments:myArrayOfArgs];` and  `JSValue *myFn2 = javascriptContext[@"myFn2"]; [myFn2 callWithArguments:myArrayOfArgs2];` where your functions are called myFn1 and myFn2 in javascript