# How can React Native read / observe native Objective-C model data?

Tags: objective-c, react-native

I'm building a native iOS application that already manages online and offline data via the Parse iOS SDK.  I've recently discovered the benefits of React Native and would like to build future features with React Native where possible.

I've already done the hard work of building model objects and managing the data in Objective-C and all I want React Native to do is to build me a view to display it.

Being React, I would also expect that whenever the Objective-C models get updated, React's view gets updated with the latest data as well: i.e. two-way data-binding. I would currently implement something like this using ReactiveCocoa's `RACChannel`s.

The problem: React Native only understands Javascript objects. While you can expose native methods through `RCT_EXPORT()` and return `NSDictionary` objects that represent a copy of the underlying data (letting [JavascriptCore perform the conversion for you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23050131/590767)) it is just a copy.

Suppose an Objective-C background thread fetches new data from the server. How is the React Native view then updated with the latest server data FROM Objective-C?

Comment: For ReactJS I found ReactLink (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html) but no such thing exists for React Native :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When building a Native Module for RN, you can send event from Obj-C to JavaScript. See the docs for Native Modules under the heading "[Sending events to JavaScript](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/nativemodulesios.html#sending-events-to-javascript)".

While this isn't a complete solution it could provide a potential solution to automatically passing from Obj-C to JS.

Comment: Yes; I can see how events might be used for this purpose. Thanks!