# JavacriptCore WebKit EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash after executing callback with data from background thread

Tags: swift, cocoa, webkit, grand-central-dispatch, javascriptcore

I'm currently trying to debug crashes in a JavascriptCore implementation of an interface for native code to perform some work on behalf of the javascript code in the WebView.

The crash sometimes occurs very soon after launching the application, other times it may take a few minutes of executing hundreds of calls to the native code for it to occur.

These are the top two lines for the backtrace of every crash:

```
(lldb) thread backtrace
* thread #1: tid = 0x37960c, 0x00007fff8de6ecca JavaScriptCore`sanitizeStackForVMImpl + 15, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x700001a2c000)
    frame #0: 0x00007fff8de6ecca JavaScriptCore`sanitizeStackForVMImpl + 15
```

Here is a simplified version of my view controller:

```
class MyViewController: NSViewController, WebFrameLoadDelegate {

    let worker = Worker() 

    // other setup code...

    func webView(webView: WebView!, didCreateJavaScriptContext context: JSContext!, forFrame frame: WebFrame!) {
        context.setObject(worker, forKeyedSubscript: "ClientWorker")
    }
}
```

The JSExport protocol itself, and implementation of the code performing work. For testing I removed the actual work and just return a dictionary with dummy data, and the crash still occurs.

```
@objc protocol WorkerJSExports: JSExport {
    func doWork(params: [String:AnyObject], callback: JSValue)
}

@objc class Worker: NSObject, WorkerJSExports {

    func doWork(params: [String:AnyObject], callback: JSValue) {
        executeBackground(callback) {
            return [
                "test": "data"
            ]
        }
    }

    private func executeBackground(callback: JSValue!, f: ()->([String:AnyObject])) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_UTILITY, 0)) {
            let result = f()
            dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.executeCallback(callback, result: result)
            }
        }
    }

    private func executeCallback(callback: JSValue!, result: AnyObject) {
        callback.context.evaluateScript("setTimeout").callWithArguments([callback, 0, result])
    }
}
```

The `executeBackground` and `executeCallback` methods are helper functions, and `executeCallback` is making use of `setTimeout` in response to what I read in this SO post/answer: [JavaScriptCore -- Passing a function as a parameter to ObjC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22790355/javascriptcore-passing-a-function-as-a-parameter-to-objc) and it seems to have resolved other crashes related to locking.

When I swap out `executeBackground` for the following function that runs just on the main thread, I have not been able to replicate the crash:

```
private func executeMain(callback: JSValue!, f: ()->([String:AnyObject])) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.executeCallback(callback, result: f())
    }
}
```

It seems that there is some sort of issue that occurs when passing data created in a background thread into the WebView, but after pouring through the documentation I'm uncertain that what could be. The only taboo I found mentioned was passing data between multiple JSVirtualMachine instances, which doesn't seem applicable since I'm only interacting with a single WebView instance. Any assistance in figuring this out is greatly appreciated!

---

### Update

I seem to have solved the issue by switching out the use of Grand Central Dispatch directly for NSOperationQueues. After changing `executeBackground` to the following, the crashes have not recurred.

```
private let workerQueue = NSOperationQueue()

private func executeAsync(callback: JSValue!, f: ()->([String:AnyObject])) {
    self.workerQueue.addOperationWithBlock({
        let result = f()
        NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({
            self.executeCallback(callback, result: result)
        })
    })
}
```

Though I can't really *prove* that this has fixed the crash, we've done fairly extensive testing of this functionality and haven't seen it again. The reason I didn't post this an an answer to my own question is that I'm at a loss as to *why* exactly this is different and/or better. If anyone has insight into what the change to NSOperationQueues may have solved, it would be very much appreciated!

Comment: What are you doing with `dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue())` in `executeBackground` function. It is supposed to be `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())`

Comment: I haven't dealt with this bit of code in a little while, but offhand I'm not sure! Still, can you clarify what is incorrect about using dispatch_sync on the main queue?